# $3 \times 3$ real matrix: relation with determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

$A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with real entries such that $\operatorname{det}(A+I_3)=\operatorname{det}(A+2I_3)$.
Then is $2\operatorname{det}(A+I_3)+\operatorname{det}(A-I_3)+ 6   =3 \operatorname{det}A$? So, if the first holds, then does the second also hold? That $6$ in the sum makes it somehow "different".
Any idea / solution?

Comment: Does the second equation follow from the first? (If yes, how?) What exactly do you want to know? Please make your question clearer.

Comment: Edited it . . .

Comment: Thanks! I do not see a way to solve this right away. Could you also include why you think this implication might be true/or not true? And please elaborate what you mean by 'different', even if you cannot give an exact definition.

Comment: I saw this once in an maths magazine...I mean the 2 relations and the first implying the second, but I didn't read the whole text and now I think the implication might be true but didn't find a proof yet. It must work (typically) with eigenvalues...Let's find a way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\lambda_{1,2,3}$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$, then $\operatorname{det}(A+I)=\operatorname{det}(A+2I)$ can be rewritten as
$$(\lambda_1+1)(\lambda_2+1)(\lambda_3+1)=(\lambda_1+2)(\lambda_2+2)(\lambda_3+2),$$
which is in turn equivalent to (check it!)
$$ \lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_1\lambda_3+\lambda_2\lambda_3+3(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)+7=0.\tag{1}$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align}
2\operatorname{det}(A+I)+\operatorname{det}(A-I)-3\operatorname{det}A+6=\\
=2(\lambda_1+1)(\lambda_2+1)(\lambda_3+1)+(\lambda_1-1)(\lambda_2-1)(\lambda_3-1)-3\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3+6=\\
=\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_1\lambda_3+\lambda_2\lambda_3+3(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)+7,\;\;
\end{align}
and this vanishes according to (1).

Comment: Note that the eigenvalues might be complex even though $A$ only has real entries. It doesn't affect the answer, but it's healthy to have in mind.